# Upsert a complete document (replace all if "Id" exists // insert if "Id" doesn't exists ) with C# Driver (MongoDB)

Tags: c#, mongodb, driver, upsert

I struggle to do a Upsert in MongoDB. I would like to accomplish this behavior:

Create a Object to upload to the DataBase (NachName=LastName // VorName=FirstName):
Class definition

```
public class NameModel
{
    [BsonId]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string  NachName { get; set; }
    public string VorName { get; set; }
    public NameModel() 
    {
        NachName = "Mustermann";
        VorName = "Max";
    }

    public NameModel(string nachName, string vorName)
    {
        NachName = nachName;
        VorName = vorName;
    }
}
```

Look if the DataBase has already a entry (document) with a given Guid (Filter = Guid). Calling the Methode:

```
NameModel name = new NameModel();
DB.UpsertDocumentByGuid<NameModel>("NameCollection", TxbGuid.Text, name);
```

And this is the Methode that is called and here is the error

```
        public void UpsertDocumentByGuid<T>(string table, string guid, T document)
    {
        var collection = db.GetCollection<T>(table);
        var filter = new BsonDocument("Id", guid);
        var update = document ;  //   ERROR    -> converting T to MongoDB.Driver.UpdateDefinition<T> not possible

        var options = new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true }; 

        var result = collection.UpdateOne(filter, update, options);
    }
```

I would like to have a methode that looks if the Guid is already there and if yes update what ever is different in the Document (compare the Document given to the Methode to the document with the found Guid) or if the Guid doent exist insert the new document in the Database.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you'd just call `Builders<YourClass>.Update.Set()` for each property you'd like to set. However, seeing as you've made it generic which I'd personally try to avoid, you could do it by building up your own BsonDocument that represents the update operation:

```cs
public static async Task UpsertDocumentByGuid<T>(string table, string guid, T document)
{
    var client = new MongoClient();
    var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
    var collection = database.GetCollection<T>(table);
    var filter = new BsonDocument("Id", guid);

    var bsonDocument = document.ToBsonDocument();
    bsonDocument.Remove("_id");
    var update = new BsonDocument()
    {
        {"$set", bsonDocument}
    };

    var options = new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true };

    var result = await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update, options);
}
```